# Angular AG-Grid - compare rows with formatting

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am new to Angular and playing around with AG Grid. Looking for some help:

I have a ag-grid with 4 columns:

```
  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { field: 'no' },
    { field: 'dateRange', cellRenderer: DateRangePickerComponent },
    { field: 'startDate', editable: true, sortable:true},
    { field: 'endDate', editable: true, sortable: true}
  ];
```

When a new startDate or endDate has been added I want to proceed with following checks:

1. if currentIndex value at startDate > previousIndex value at endDate both cells should be highlited in red.
2. if currentIndex value at endDate > nextIndex value at startDate both cells should be highlited in red
3. if 1 & 2 is not applying not highlithing

Option 1: does it make sense to implement that via onCellValueChanged event?
onCellValueChanged(event: any) {
console.log('TestStart: ', this.gridApi.getValue('startDate', this.gridApi.getRowNode('2')));
How can I access the value of a certain cell here? It returns only null here.
}

Option 2: Is it possible to define that rules in defaultColDef?
Similar to following? (does not work)

```
defaultColDef = {
    cellStyle: function(params) {
        const rowIndex = params.node.rowIndex;
        const columnId = params.colDef.field;
        const previousRowIndex = rowIndex - 1;
        const nextRowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
        const currentValueStart = params.value;
        const currentValueEnd = params.value;
        const previousValueEnd = params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(previousRowIndex).data[columnId];;
        const nextValueStart = params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(nextRowIndex).data[columnId];

        if (currentValueStart < previousValueEnd) || (currentValueEnd > nextValueStart {
          return { 'background-color': 'red' };
        }
  
        return { 'background-color': null};
      }
}
```

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Please could you create a stackblitz or similar with some data?  Or even a picture that's been labelled with what you want to achieve